# Longtable not starting immediately after section tittle

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I have been trying to fix this problem by reading many posts for the last two day and I have not been successful.

I have a long table that spreads over three pages and I want to start after the section title.

I don't now what causes the page break. I have tried `\clearspace`, `\needspace` and `\FloatBarrier` among others I can't remember now.

I would appreciate any guidance!

I have provided a shorter version of my document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,left=1.25in,right=1.25in]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{sectsty}
    \sectionfont{\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}
    \subsectionfont{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{placeins}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{needspace}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}[H!]{@{}cccccccc@{}}
\caption{Absolute displacements obtained from the static analysis}\\
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Joint}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{OutputCase}} & \textbf{U1} & \textbf{U2} & \textbf{U3} & \textbf{R1} & \textbf{R2} & \textbf{R3} \\
 &  & ft & ft & ft & Radians & Radians & Radians \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{\textit{\textemdash{}Continued}}\\
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Joint}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{OutputCase}} & \textbf{U1} & \textbf{U2} & \textbf{U3} & \textbf{R1} & \textbf{R2} & \textbf{R3} \\
 &  & ft & ft & ft & Radians & Radians & Radians \\ \midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule \endfoot
\endlastfoot

1 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -5.000E-01 & 0.000E+00 & 4.100E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
2 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 5.816E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
3 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -4.969E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
4 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.149E-06 & -1.056E-08 \\
5 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.609E-06 & 1.783E-08 \\
6 & Settle - DL & 7.148E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.087E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
7 & Settle - DL & 4.914E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -7.058E-08 & 0.000E+00 \\
8 & Settle - DL & 4.328E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -2.593E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
9 & Settle - DL & 4.022E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.812E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
10 & Settle - DL & 1.854E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -4.575E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
11 & Settle - DL & 2.349E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 6.551E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
12 & Settle - DL & 9.812E-08 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.600E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
13 & Settle - DL & 8.270E-07 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -4.184E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
14 & Settle - DL & 7.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.479E-06 & -3.821E-07 \\
15 & Settle - DL & 6.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.461E-06 & -3.929E-07 \\
16 & Settle - DL & 5.500E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.539E-06 & -3.398E-07 \\
17 & Settle - DL & 4.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.372E-06 & -3.362E-07 \\
18 & Settle - DL & 3.400E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.588E-06 & -2.313E-07 \\
19 & Settle - DL & 2.800E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.386E-06 & -2.207E-07 \\
20 & Settle - DL & 1.100E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.614E-06 & -1.148E-07 \\
21 & Settle - DL & 8.219E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.224E-06 & -1.605E-07 \\
121 & Settle - DL & -7.327E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 7.700E-05 & -5.503E-07 \\
122 & Settle - DL & -5.483E-07 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.709E-08 & 0.000E+00 \\
123 & Settle - DL & 2.418E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.322E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
124 & Settle - DL & 2.363E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 6.062E-08 & 0.000E+00 \\
125 & Settle - DL & 2.345E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 9.417E-08 & 3.309E-07 \\
126 & Settle - DL & 5.060E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.600E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
127 & Settle - DL & 5.080E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.600E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
128 & Settle - DL & 5.080E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.600E-05 & -1.400E-05 \\
129 & Settle - DL & -9.299E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.600E-05 & -3.990E-06 \\
130 & Settle - DL & -5.234E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -2.723E-06 & 1.090E-06 \\
131 & Settle - DL & -7.327E-07 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -2.300E-05 & -5.499E-07 \\
132 & Settle - DL & 7.833E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.700E-05 & -6.579E-07 \\
133 & Settle - DL & 3.748E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -4.226E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
134 & Settle - DL & 2.804E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 5.619E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
135 & Settle - DL & 2.927E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 7.289E-08 & 0.000E+00 \\
136 & Settle - DL & 2.962E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 8.291E-08 & 4.645E-07 \\
137 & Settle - DL & 1.027E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.200E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
138 & Settle - DL & 1.025E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.300E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
139 & Settle - DL & 1.025E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.800E-05 & -2.800E-05 \\
140 & Settle - DL & -1.400E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.900E-05 & -6.398E-06 \\
141 & Settle - DL & -1.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.318E-06 & 1.613E-06 \\
142 & Settle - DL & -2.000E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.200E-05 & -8.023E-07 \\
143 & Settle - DL & 4.399E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.700E-05 & -8.006E-07 \\
144 & Settle - DL & 5.284E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.578E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
145 & Settle - DL & 4.862E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.923E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
146 & Settle - DL & 4.711E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.888E-08 & 0.000E+00 \\
147 & Settle - DL & 4.681E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 7.449E-08 & 7.542E-07 \\
148 & Settle - DL & 1.561E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.500E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
149 & Settle - DL & 1.561E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.300E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
150 & Settle - DL & 1.561E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.900E-05 & -4.100E-05 \\
151 & Settle - DL & -2.300E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.900E-05 & -8.542E-06 \\
152 & Settle - DL & -2.200E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.292E-06 & 2.094E-06 \\
153 & Settle - DL & -2.400E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.400E-05 & -1.024E-06 \\
154 & Settle - DL & 3.100E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 8.500E-05 & -8.402E-07 \\
155 & Settle - DL & 1.100E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.708E-06 & 0.000E+00 \\
156 & Settle - DL & 2.756E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.572E-06 & 0.000E+00 \\
157 & Settle - DL & 2.827E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.012E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
158 & Settle - DL & 2.840E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -2.332E-07 & 8.334E-07 \\
159 & Settle - DL & 2.121E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 5.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
160 & Settle - DL & 2.115E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.500E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
161 & Settle - DL & 2.115E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 4.000E-05 & -5.600E-05 \\
162 & Settle - DL & -2.000E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 5.000E-05 & -9.998E-06 \\
163 & Settle - DL & -3.200E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.969E-06 & 2.630E-06 \\
164 & Settle - DL & -4.600E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -3.700E-05 & -1.307E-06 \\
166 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.168E-07 & 0.000E+00 \\
167 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -5.000E-01 & 0.000E+00 & 2.035E-07 & 3.309E-07 \\
168 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.200E-05 & 0.000E+00 \\
171 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.333E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 3.600E-05 & -1.400E-05 \\
172 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 6.682E-07 & 5.209E-07 \\
173 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.000E-05 & -5.499E-07 \\
174 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -3.800E-05 & -5.503E-07 \\
175 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -2.300E-05 & -3.588E-06 \\
176 & Settle - DL & 1.800E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.510E-06 & -2.128E-07 \\
177 & Settle - DL & 2.200E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.560E-06 & -1.895E-07 \\
178 & Settle - DL & 2.710E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.900E-05 & -9.837E-06 \\
179 & Settle - DL & -3.674E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -2.975E-07 & 6.671E-08 \\
180 & Settle - DL & 1.860E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.300E-05 & -1.200E-05 \\
181 & Settle - DL & 3.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.398E-06 & -2.880E-07 \\
182 & Settle - DL & 4.500E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.563E-06 & -2.977E-07 \\
183 & Settle - DL & 5.430E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.900E-05 & -2.000E-05 \\
184 & Settle - DL & -8.153E-06 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -3.441E-07 & 4.369E-07 \\
185 & Settle - DL & 3.760E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.400E-05 & -2.200E-05 \\
186 & Settle - DL & 5.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.433E-06 & -3.829E-07 \\
187 & Settle - DL & 6.600E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.504E-06 & -3.778E-07 \\
188 & Settle - DL & 8.160E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.000E-05 & -2.900E-05 \\
189 & Settle - DL & -1.300E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -3.861E-07 & 5.775E-07 \\
191 & Settle - DL & 5.750E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.500E-05 & -3.400E-05 \\
192 & Settle - DL & -1.900E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -4.525E-07 & 9.678E-07 \\
193 & Settle - DL & 7.820E-04 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.500E-05 & -4.600E-05 \\
194 & Settle - DL & 7.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.538E-06 & -3.978E-07 \\
195 & Settle - DL & 8.700E-05 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.456E-06 & -3.795E-07 \\
196 & Settle - DL & 1.089E-03 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 2.000E-05 & -4.100E-05 \\
197 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.900E-05 & -9.837E-06 \\
198 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -2.452E-07 & 6.671E-08 \\
199 & Settle - DL & 0.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & -1.000E+00 & 0.000E+00 & 1.300E-05 & -1.700E-05 \\ \bottomrule
\label{AbsoluteDisp}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is the shorter version, I can't imagine the longer one. :P

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Just adding `\section{this is a section}` before `\begin{longtable}` works fine. See [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4x1NK.png).

Comment: No way let me check what is different in my code from the one I pasted

Comment: I found out what was causing it. I had changed the margins around the table so it would be centered on the page. If I include the section title inside the temporary margins for the table, the table starts right after it! 
Thanks for helping me see this! I can't believe I did not see that!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue that's not mentioned or discernible in the posting and was fixed by the OP using information not provided in the posting.

Comment: @AlexandraHernandez No problem, but make sure to double-test next time. :) And also, welcome to Tex SE.

Comment: How do I close the question?

Comment: You delete your own question if you want.